# Enviroment dinamico. ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic-framework, environment

Estoy con un tema con un trabajo nuevo y no se como resolverlo.
La aplicacion tiene el siguiente **environment.ts** =>

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  api: {
    baseUrlApi: 'https://demo.api.io/',
    baseUrlImages: 'https://demo-api.io/',
    client_id:'blablblbl',
    client_secret: 'blblititi',
  },
}
```

Desde el front, el cliente tiene que cambiar la ubicacion eligiendo entre 3 paises.
Dependiendo esa entrada de paises que tengo, debo modificar o agregar la baseUrlApi, dependiendo cada pais.

Es decir paso a paso lo que tengo que hacer:
1- desde el front se elige el pais.
2- recibo el dato de que pais es.
3- en base a ese dato, modificar o agregar una nueva baseUrlApi.

Tengo que modificar la baseUrlApi?.
Tengo que agregar un nuevo objeto al environment.ts ? =>

```
export const enviromentBrasil ={
  baseUrlApi:"....."
  ......
}
```

tengo bastantes dudas como debo hacerlo, y de como llamar a mi archivo **environment.ts**, no se si hacerlo con FS, llamando al archivo.
Tengo muchas dudas y pocas certezas.
**gracias por su ayuda como siempre.**

Comment: Modificar el valor de `baseUrlApi` es buena idea.

Comment: Hola ! si, solo con modificarlo me alcanzo! gracias por tu respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

mi solucion fue mas sencilla de lo que creia:

```
 getItemCountry(code){
    this.codeCountry = code;
    console.log(this.codeCountry,"CodeCountry");
    console.log(environment.api.baseUrlApi,"Base URL API ORIGINAL");
    if(this.codeCountry==="MX"){
      environment.api.baseUrlApi = "https://apiMX/";
      console.log(environment.api.baseUrlApi);
    }if(this.codeCountry==="EC"){
      environment.api.baseUrlApi = "ApiEC";
      console.log(environment.api.baseUrlApi);
    }if(this.codeCountry==="AR"){
      environment.api.baseUrlApi = "https://apiAR/";
      console.log(environment.api.baseUrlApi);
    }if(this.codeCountry===undefined){
      this.msgerror="Debe seleccionar país";
    };
  }
```

Solo con entrar al archivo **environment.ts**, y tratarlo como cualquier objeto, me dejo hacerlo, nada mas. es decir, le asigno al campo base url el string que necesito y listo!

**Gracias como siempre!**